# Cannot get wrapper to contain elements or change color

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I'm building an amateur website to pass a course that gets me into university. I'm finding it hard to manipulate my wrapper element so that it encompasses the whole page and has a different color to the rest of my background.
I want it to be black, against the grey background.

Unfortunately my tutor has said he cant help me with my code. I have searched a lot and have tried clearing the elements but it is not working..

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou you clever people

:]

```js
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 background-color:#A6A6A6;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 2px;
 font-size:32px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

h2 {
 font-size:26px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:link, a:visited {
 color: green;
}

#nav ul li a { 
 color: #ff0000;
}

a:hover {
 color: green;
}

#wrapper {
 width:1024px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 color: #000000;
}

#search {
 float:right;
 margin-top: -50px;
}

/* These are additional to make the text box look nicer!! */
#search input {
 border: 2px solid #66CCFF;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align:right;
}

#search input:focus {
 border-color: #B7901E;
}

#nav {
 /* Fallback if gradient doesn't work */
 background-color:#B7901E; 
 /*Safari $+, Chrome 1-9 */
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#333333), to(#000000));  /*Make black to show the difference!! */
    /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #000000); 
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #B7901E, #7B612C);
    /* IE 10+ */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #B7901E, #7B612C);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #B7901E, #7B612C);
 text-align:center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 70px;
 border-top: 1px solid #000000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

/*Delete <hr/> tags from html and change backround color of image to white*/ 

#nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
 display:inline;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: none;
}

/* Make the links in the HTML hyperlinks */

#nav ul li a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #FF0000;
 text-decoration:underline;
}

#nav ul li:after {
 padding: 30px;
 content: " | " ;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

#nav ul li:last-child:after {
 content: "";
}

#photos, #content {
              width: 926px;
              margin: 0 auto;
}
 

#article {
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 margin-right: 2%;
}

#sidenav {
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
 margin-left:auto;
}

#video {
  float:right;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.highlight {
 color:#FF0000;
}
#Vegas-banner {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Las Vegas</title>
<link href="mywebsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
<div id="header">
   <div id="search">
         <input type="text" value="search ..." />
    </div>
  <div id="nav">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Casinos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drinking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>  
   </div>
   </div>

<img src="Images/Vegas banner.jpg" alt="Images of vegas" style="align-content:center;>


  <div id="photos">   
     <ul>
     <img name="Hotels" src="images/Chip-hotels.png" width="220" height="245" alt="" img style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;"/>
     <img name="Gambling" src="images/Chip-casinos.png" width="220" height="245" alt="" img style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;"/>
     <img name="Drinking" src="images/Chip-drinking.png" width="220" height="245" alt="" img style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;"/>
     <img name="Activities" src="images/Chip-activities.png" width="220" height="245" alt="" img style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;"/>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="content">
     <div id="article">
   <h2>Floated Divs</h2>
   <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet pork chop bacon salami, hamburger sausage jerky andouille chuck prosciutto. Frankfurter venison filet mignon, prosciutto short ribs brisket corned beef jowl meatloaf shankle boudin. <span class="highlight">Pancetta ham capicola flank</span> boudin jerky. Ham meatball boudin capicola ground round shankle, short loin spare ribs pastrami short ribs bresaola shoulder andouille tail. Jowl cow rump pork chop sausage fatback. <span class="highlight">Shoulder shank frankfurter</span>, fatback beef ribs meatball corned beef pancetta pork chop tongue t-bone.</p>
   <p>Shank tongue beef, bacon strip steak biltong beef ribs meatball sausage jerky t-bone turkey short loin filet mignon short ribs. Tenderloin ground round pork chop short ribs rump drumstick. Salami pancetta chicken, sausage meatloaf bacon ball tip chuck hamburger rump jerky pig short loin. <a href="http://www.edgehill.ac.uk" target="_blank">Link to Edge Hill Web Site</a></p>
  </div><!-- End of article -->
        <div id="video">
          <iframe width="300" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1Y4R3A0nrh0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="sidenav">
          <h2>Bulleted List</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Point One</li>
                <li>Point Two</li>
                <li>Point Three</li>
                <li>Point Four</li>
                <li>Point Five</li>
            </ul>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h3>Numbered List</h3>
            <ol>
              <li>Number One</li>
              <li>Number Two</li>
              <li>Number Three</li>
              <li>Number Four</li>
              <li>Number Five</li>
            </ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply the css background property

```
#wrapper {
width:1024px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #000000;
color:#fff;
}
```

[edit in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvinzach/cLwgu6nu/)